# Azure services not listing anything

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to Azure. I know this is weird question. 
But, when I am creating any Storage Account or a VM or say any service instance, I am not able to list it in the service listing after creating. Looks like its created but disappeared. 
Due to it, Azure is charging me as I cannot delete the service(e.g a VM) that I created.

Anyone has any insight into this.

[image: Storage Account is not listing anything]

[image: One of the Storage Account that I created]

Comment: what is your subscription offer?

Comment: That's totally weird! I am wondering if somehow browser is caching the content. Can you try in other browser or may be do a hard refresh? Also, try to use Azure PowerShell or CLI and see if the resources are displayed there.

Comment: pay as you go. I have expired the 30 days trial

Comment: Yes tried in Firefox and Edge. Same result

Answer (score 1):

You can list/delete it with by using [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) or [Azure Powershell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.1.0).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try checking the notification panel on the top right. Whatever resources are created, it will appear in notification saving "deployed/in progress/etc". Click on go to resource if notification shows it. Also check the dashboard page, if any recent resources are available.
[Image shows the home page with recent resources and showing the notification panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfuFH.png)

You can also check your cost analysis. Go to your subscription -> Click on Pay-as-you-go -> Under cost management -> Cost Analysis.

Cost Analysis will tell you, for what services and resources you are getting charged. You can filter the result and view it by resource.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes while creating resources I do get the notification, and only during that time only I could access the resource but as I told the problem is of listing the already created resource. I couldn't even track anything on cost management page.